# Storyboard imageview questions

Tags: ios, storyboard

I am planning to make an iPhone application using storyboard.It will contain about 20 High quality pictures from a religuos book.I am new to programming ios apps hence forgive me if the questions are very basic.
My question are

1. When I run the program the whole image is seen on the 4 inch simulator but on the 3.5 inch simulator the bottom part of the image cant be seen.How do I use auto-layout so that the whole image can be seen on both the simulators.
2. I am using swipe gesture recogniser to move to the next page.Means if I swipe from left to right new page will be shown.Now I want to implement that if the user has to go to the previous page he has to swype from right to left.How to do that.
3. Is it possible to implement a navigator on the botom of the screen in which the user can select he wants to go 5 pages ahead,5 pages back.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can Pin the image to bottom view. But then, the aspect ratio of the image may change when viewed in a 3.5" screen.

Comment: a simple tutorial about auto layout
http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Answer (score 0):

**For 1:**

1. Select the screen in story board.
2. Click on **Resolve Autolayout Issues** option .
3. Select Clear all Constraints.
4. Click on **Resolve Autolayout Issues** option
5. Select Add missing Constraints .

**For 2:**

We can apply two many swipe gesture to a single UI Object(say image view) with different 
Directions.

EX:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe  = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:nil action:nil];
[swipe setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipe];
```

Make use :***UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft*** and **UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight**

**For 3:** Make use **UIPageControl** .

Answer (score 0):

1) You should select the controller in the storyboard and go to the first of the six options on the right panel. Make sure that the `autolayout` option is unchecked otherwise uncheck it. Then go to the fifth options i.e `properties` and turn on the springs. For more about springs and struts, read this:

```
http://msmvps.com/blogs/kevinmcneish/archive/2012/12/10/tutorial-ios-6-auto-layout-versus-springs-and-struts.aspx
```

2) To detect swipe right and swipe left, you need to use these two methods: **setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft** and **setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight**

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipedLeft:)];
[swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft ];
[_view1 addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
[swipeLeft release];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]  initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipedRight:)];
[swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight ];
[_view1 addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
[swipeRight release];
```

and these two IBActions:

```
- (IBAction)swipedRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"swiped right");
}

- (IBAction)swipedLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"swiped left");
}
```

3) **UIPageControl** will help you do this. You can get a reference here:
        https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uipagecontrol_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply.Forgive me for asking this,Where to write the code that you have written in the second point.

Comment: You will write the above code in your viewcontroller class. The top snippet of code will be written inside viewDidLoad method and the second code snippet will be written after the viewDidLoad method or anywhere else outside any other function in the same controller class

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.After writing the code i am getting 2 errors.Apple Mach-O Linker Error.Request for help.

Comment: The above errors got solved by writing self.view1 instead of _view1.
 [swipeLeft release] and [swipeRight release] gives me this error release is unavailable in arc.
Also when i run the project(by writing the release code as comment) and swipe right the console displays swiped right but nothing gets implemented on the simulator.Request for help.

Comment: release is only available in non-arc environments. If you are using arc then you should delete the two lines with release from the code. If you can send me your code, I can look into it in detail to see what probably you are encountering

Comment: How can i send the code to you?Because i have used storyboard to put images.Also when i am writing self.view1 its giving me error message property not found on object.And thanks a ton for your constant help.